# Can't add class on beforeShowDate of datepicker when return false

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

In order to make some dates disabled on jQuery datepicker, I do the following:

```
beforeShowDay: function(d) {
     if(endDate!==""){
        var endDayFinal=new Date(endDate);
          return [false,"myClass","After goal end date"];
     }
     else { 
          return [true,"myClass2","before goal start date"];
     }
}
```

The  problem is that only when I return **true** the class is added and also the text appears on hover.

On disabled days (when it returns false), it doesn't appear, neither the class is added, but days are disabled as I wanted... What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

One fix i found was to add on my style the following:

```
.ui-state-disabled span{
/*here goes the css i want...*/
}`
```

Though, i still can't add text on hover.